# Django migrations: how to conditionally switch between migration statements according to current DB backend?

Tags: python, django, database

I use Django with SQLite in my dev environment and postgreSQL in production. I know that having different DB backends for dev and prod is a tech debt, but this is the current state of affairs for now (not for long, hopefully).

I would like to take advantage of the postgres JSONField in production while in dev keep using [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield). Is there a way to write a migration so that it can conditionally switch between the two types of field depending on which backend is currently being used?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting. I thought this would be a duplicate question, or that a straightforward way to do this would be documented, but if so I can't find it.

The documentation does have a section about [Data migrations and multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#data-migrations-and-multiple-databases), but the techniques there only apply to `RunPython` and `RunSQL` operations. They are:

1. Add a `hints` argument to your `RunPython` or `RunSQL` operation. That value will be passed to the database router, where you can decide whether or not the operation should be applied.
2. Within the `RunPython` function, check `schema_editor.connection.alias` to determine which database is being used, and switch on that. Unfortunately, the `schema_editor` isn't exposed on the `Migration` class.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/migration.py), you could override the `apply()` method, since that does expose the `schema_editor`.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [...]

    operations = [...]

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        if schema_editor.connection.alias == "my_sqlite_database":
            return super().apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=collect_sql)
        else:
            return project_state
```

Please note that this is untested, and relies on undocumented behavior. I hope a better solution exists.

Comment: note that `alias` is the name of the db in settings.py, most of the time that'll be `default`. Use connection.vendor for the type, which could be `sqlite`, `oracle` etc.